# My server IP routing problem

Tags: domain-name-system, routing, route, nslookup

I am unfortunately from Iran and I have a Problem with my server.
when I type in windows CMD nslookup **ParsCMS.com 4.2.2.4** it can not find my server IP, but  **nslookup ParsCMS.com 8.8.4.4** returns 79.175.165.139 but every one can ping my server so problem is not firewall and my server.
in our country lots of people use 4.2.2.4 as their Primary DNS Sevrer and my site is in persian so most of visitors are from Iran?! lots of peaple in my country can not route to my site, I am afraid that search engine crawlers cant route to my server.
on the other hand My sites were in IWEB Canada And USA but visitors from my country could not route to them correctly, so I moved my server to my country.
Now Please help me,I am a CMS and It would make me bankrupt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a routing problem, it's a DNS problem. Everyone *can* route to your site, they just can't look up the IP address from the domain name. Your DNS appears to be set up correctly, so the problem is probably with 4.2.2.4. 4.2.2.4 appears to be owned by Level 3, so I wouldn't worry about search engines -- they'll be using their own DNS setups, and as I say, your DNS appears to be set up correctly.

Your best bet is to get a Level 3 customer to raise a query with them.

Answer (score 1):

DNS changes take time to propagate depending on the TTL that you've configured, as it's designed to be heavily cached by both recursive servers and clients.

You didn't leave long enough for the server to get the updated info, it's just fine now.